# Event firing when it shouldnt

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found some code which enables me to obtain URL query strings

```
var QueryURL = function () {
      var query_url = {};
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (typeof query_url[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
          query_url[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        } else if (typeof query_url[pair[0]] === "string") {
          var arr = [ query_url[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
          query_url[pair[0]] = arr;
        } else {
          query_url[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
        }
      }
      return query_url;
}();
```

The above code works perfectly.  There is something I am not quite getting however.  I am doing the following

```
$( ".search" ).click(function(e) {

    console.log(QueryURL.someID); //outputs undefined

    if(QueryURL.someID !==  "undefined") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "someurl",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data)
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So if I do not provide the URL with a query someID, then it should not execute the Ajax call.  Now the console logging outputs undefined, as I expect it too.  However, for some reason it is still firing the Ajax request even though I have a condition that should stop this from happening.

Why would it still make the ajax request if `QueryURL.someID` is undefined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"undefined"` is a string, you need to compare with variable `undefined`

`if(QueryURL.someID !==  undefined) {
 //ajax call
}`

From MDN:

> The global undefined property represents the primitive value undefined. It is one of JavaScript's primitive types.

Comment: Perfect, so QueryURL is returning a variable called undefined, not a string?

Comment: `QueryURL` is returning an object and `someID` is its property. If property `someID` is not set, it returns value undefined.